# How do I change OMXplayer's default volume?

Tags: audio, omxplayer

The title pretty much says it all. I am using Ubuntu MATE, which uses ALSA instead of PulseAudio. OMXplayer bypasses ALSA. Because of this OMXplayer always starts playback at 100% volume, which is far too loud (dive for cover and grab some earmuffs!). I would like to reset the default volume so this does not happen.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a pixel desktop? If so why can't you use volume control instead? Or do you mean that OMXplayer resets the volume to 100%?

Comment: @Darkest N2O, I forgot got to mention that I am using Ubuntu MATE. The Ubuntu MATE desktop uses ALSA, which has no control over OMXplayer.

Comment: sorry cant help you. I have never used Ubuntu before...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are starting `omxplayer` from the command line you can use the `--vol` option to set the volume at start.

```
$man omxplayer
...
-b 
   --vol n                 set initial volume in millibels (default 0)
```

You can do a trial and error experiment with a few values and see which one is best suited to your likes.  Then you can create an `alias` for `omxplayer -b --vol nnnn`

It's important to note that the units are millibels not decibels.  So, a value of `-50` is not going to do much.  Since the scale is logarithmic, 3.0dB is twice or one half power.  So, the `-3000` set point is one half power of the default `0` setting.

**How to set an alias**

```
#alias omxplayer="omxplayer -b --vol -1000"
```

It's important to remember that the alias needs to be created in the proper user's environment.  So, if you run `omxplayer` as `root`, you will need to create the alias in a `root` shell.

```
$sudo -s
```

Comment: For those who do not know [how to create a permanent alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

I am also using ubuntu mate loaded on Raspberry pi 2 model B.

you can increase-decrease volume in omxplayer by following command:

omxplayer -o local --vol -1000 name.mp3 (0 to -1000.... is for low volume set)

omxplayer -o local --vol 1000 name.mp3 (0 to 1000.... is for high volume set)

you can check omxplayer's option by enter- omxplayer on terminal.

it will help you.